# A-painterでローカル通信上で行う際について

Tags: javascript, html, https, three.js

私はA-painterというVRペイントソフトを使用して拡張可能なため様々な要素を入れて描画したいと考えており、ローカル開発が可能なため、ローカル通信上で描画を行おうとしております。
しかし、ローカル通信を行った際に「Access this site over HTTPS to enter VR mode and grant access to the device sensors.」と表示され、その表記を消した後VR状態にするとYouTubeビデオバーのように、ビデオ再生ボタンやズームバーなどが表示されます。この状態では、コントローラーを使って描画することはできないため、どうすれば解除できるのか知っている人がいれば教えて頂きたいです。

質問している情報が少なくて申し訳ございません。
https://github.com/aframevr/a-painter

Answer (score 0):

APIによってはセキュリティのためにHTTPSかローカルホストでだけ使えるように[制限](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)されているものがあります。
VRで使われる[WebXR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XRSystem)もこの制限に該当するようです。
アクセス先が、自分のホスト名やLANのIPアドレスではなく、厳密にループバックアドレスか確認してみてください。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトで確認したところ、ルークバックアドレス(ループバックアドレス？)は「http://localhost:8080/」でした。サイトに英語で「次に、ブラウザにhttp://localhost:8080をロードします。」と書いてあるため間違いないと思います。
localhost側(PC)では、コントローラーがないため結局動かせない状況に変わりない(a-painterはVR上でしか動かない)のですが、これはPC上で使えるVRコントローラーが必要でしょうか？
また、制限しているコードを調べる必要もありますか？